# Unexpected argument: --snapshot

Tags: ignite, snapshot

I am running apache-ignite ver 2.15.0, In one of the clusters snapshot command is not getting accepted.

**I get the following result
Control utility [ver. 2.15.0#20230425-sha1:f98f7f35]
2019 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
User: ignite
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
Check arguments.
Error: Unexpected argument: --snapshot

I another cluster command is getting executed just fine.
Can someone please help us about what could be root cause of this error. Both clusters use exactly the same ignite version 2.15.0.

I tried checking if there is any issue in the control.sh file. tried comparing versions of the libs folder jars and other scripts in bin folder. Everything seem to be exactly same.

Comment: Can you please double-check that there are no non-ASCII characters in the argument? Also, can you provide a full command that you run?

Comment: We found the root cause, we have some old custom jars packed with ignite which were causing problem.Thanks for replying.